# How to save the contents of a rich textbox without RTF formatting tags?

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I just want to save the contents of a rich textbox into a TXT file and keep everything in it in the format that it is (as far as spaces, new lines, and tabs are concerned, but I don't care if colors and fonts are lost), but they're always saved as RTF files.

Even I specify a txt file the results still look like:

```
({\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green128\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;})
```

How can I make it just save the contents without those tags?

Comment: What is the problem with `richTextBox.SaveFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);`

Comment: simply save the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

Use `richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)` instead of `RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText`